# How to create a query with query_string using Elasticsearch Java Api

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, elasticsearch

Currently my query request body looks like

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "file",
      "query": "Email OR @gmail.com @yahoo.com"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "file": {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

My java code looks like

```
String queryString = "{" 
                + "\"query_string\": " 
                    + "{"
                        + "\"default_field\":"
                    + " \"file\","
                            + " \"query\": \"Email OR @gmail.com @yahoo.com\""
                            + "}"
                            + "}";
```

with following API calls

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch()
                .setIndices("resume")
     .setTypes("docs").setQuery(queryString).addHighlightedField("file");

SearchResponse response = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

I would prefer a more api based approach  for "queryString" part.I am not able to find any api which handles "query_string" part of the request. There are apis for match_all,match, term so on and so forth but not for query_string

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`QueryBuilders` is the factory for creating any query including `query_string`. From [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/query-dsl-queries.html#query-string):

```
import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.*;
QueryBuilder qb = queryStringQuery("+kimchy -elasticsearch");
```

Your query would be built as follows:

```
QueryBuilder qb = queryStringQuery("Email OR @gmail.com @yahoo.com").defaultField("file");
```

And the full example would be:

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch()
            .setIndices("resume")
 .setTypes("docs").setQuery(qb).addHighlightedField("file");

SearchResponse response = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: I tried this , but somehow was getting ParseException, Can you please take a look at provided JSON and update what it might look like with that particular json

Comment: Can you add that ParseException to your question so that we can know more about your problem?